# Can Google Cloud Functions use HTTPS client authentication?

Tags: node.js, https, google-cloud-functions, ssl-client-authentication

Can I use HTTPS client certificate authentication with HTTPS-triggered [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)?

I stand-alone `node.js`, I would try something [like this](https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2):

```
var https = require('https'); 
var options = {requestCert: true, rejectUnauthorized: true}; 
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) { 
  // ...
}).listen(1234);
```

But since Google Cloud Functions (presumably) controls the creation of the `node.js` server, it is currently unclear to me how I could pass the required options.

Google offers [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authentication-in-http-cloud-functions) on how to use (OAuth 2.0) service accounts and access tokens for authentication, but I am interested in HTTPS client certificates, such as a web browser could also present.

Comment: There's nothing to indicate this is possible on Google's Cloud Function documentation page for the execution environment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec

This might be helpful for confirming: "Cloud Functions uses a Debian-based execution environment and includes contents of the gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs Docker image. To see what is included in the image, you can check its GitHub project, or pull and inspect the image itself": https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker

Comment: Have you found anything ? I need to do this as well

Comment: @GeoffreyHug Nops, havn't found any solution to this.

Comment: @Drux I found this https://github.com/ripjar/passport-client-cert. I didn't have time to look into it thoroughly but I think it might do the job.